# Why would a google.maps.Marker.shape not be applied?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I have three Google Maps. These are custom image maps with PNG based markers.

The first map works as intended along with the custom shapes for the markers. The first map was originally directly instanced, and it did not use promise architecture calls. I changed it later but I'll keep the events in order.

With the first map working, I duplicated the implementation to a second and third map. Except for context, the second map is identical to the first other than a set of toggled polygon borders not being included. In both the first and second case each marker is initialised with an icon and a shape object set in the marker's constructor.

```
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: mmap,
        icon: ticon,
        shape: tshape,
        title: mtitle,
        mycategory: mgroup,
        maptype: mtype,
      });
```

The third implementation includes a multiple floor design with modifying markers "attached" to certain floors. While the markers are constructed the same way, after init and during every floor change, `setIcon`, `setShape`, and `setZIndex` are called to set these values based on the current floor.

I can not confirm when the second map's shapes were failing to function. I can only confirm I'd noticed when I'd moved on to the third map. At this point I'd placed all icons into a single document when I was adding more images and then modified the points of the shapes. I'd changed the images to 42px square standard and changed all of the shapes' data. The new icons are implemented in all three maps.

In the first map, the markers and shapes function perfectly. In the second map, the shape of the icon defaults to the 42px square of the image. In the third map, no matter if set in the structure or modified by the `set~` function, the shapes default to the 42px square.

For example, I'll point to the first and second maps.
[Map 1](https://mithyr.com/hlmap/w_map.php)
[Map 2](https://mithyr.com/hlmap/hm_map.php)

Map implementation from map 2 without header and other PHP and script for controls. This is identical to map 1 except for certain variable names:

```
    let map;

    async function initialize() {
      const { Core } = await google.maps.importLibrary("core");
      const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");

      map = new Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: {lat: 58.0602, lng: -5.6062,}, // center map lat lng here,
        zoom: 3,
        backgroundColor: "#111111",
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT,
          mapTypeIds: [] //type list
        },
      }, );

      // map objects
      const mapHogsmeade = {
        getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
          var numTiles = 1 << zoom;
          if (coord.y < 0 || coord.y >= numTiles) { return null; }
          if (coord.x < 0 || coord.x >= numTiles) { return null; }

          var str = "";
          str += zoom;
          if (coord.x < 10) str += "0";
          if (coord.x < 100) str += "0";
          str += coord.x;
          if (coord.y < 10) str += "0";
          if (coord.y < 100) str += "0";
          str += coord.y;

          return "https://" + location.hostname + "/hlmap/hm/" + str + ".png";
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(200, 200),
        isPng: true,
        maxZoom: 6,
        minZoom: 1,
        name: "Hogsmeade",
      };

      const hogsmeadeMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(mapHogsmeade);
      hogsmeadeMapType.projection = {
        worldOrigin_: new google.maps.Point(2129.5, -20943.5),
        scl: 362.50,
        fromLatLngToPoint: function (latLng) {
          var x = this.worldOrigin_.x + this.scl * latLng.lng();
          var y = this.worldOrigin_.y + this.scl * latLng.lat();
          return new google.maps.Point(x, y);
        },
        fromPointToLatLng: function (point) {
          var lng = (point.x - this.worldOrigin_.x) / this.scl;
          var lat = (point.y - this.worldOrigin_.y) / this.scl;
          return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        },
      };

      //attach maps to type list  
      map.mapTypes.set('Hogsmeade Map', hogsmeadeMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId('Hogsmeade Map'); //set current map to most recent

      initIcons();
      loadMarkerFiles(map);

      map.addListener('maptypeid_changed', function () {
      });

      var infoWindow;
      map.addListener("click", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
        // Create a new InfoWindow.
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng,
        });
        infoWindow.setContent(
          '<pre>\"lat\": ' + mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lat().toFixed(6) + ',\n\"lng\": ' + mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lng().toFixed(6) + '</pre>'
        );
        infoWindow.open(map);
      });
    }

    initialize();

    /***********
     * Pins
    ************/
    var oPins = new Array();

    // Pin icon objects
    let AccioPageImage;
    let AssignmentImage;
    let CairnDungeonImage;
    let CollectionChestImage;
    let DemiguiseStatueImage;
    let EyeChestImage;
    let FieldGuidePageImage;
    let FlooNodeImage;
    let GeneralChestImage;
    let HerbSourceImage;
    let InflammariBrazierImage;
    let LegendaryChestImage;
    let LeviosoStatueImage;
    let LoreLetterImage;
    let LargeBagImage;
    let MainQuestImage;
    let MarkImage;
    let FrameMothImage;
    let MothFrameImage;
    let RelationshipQuestImage;
    let ShopPointImage;
    let SideQuestImage;
    let SmallPouchImage;
    function initIcons() {
      AccioPageImage = {
        url: 'icon//apg__1.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      AssignmentImage = {
        url: 'icon//aqs__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      CairnDungeonImage = {
        url: 'icon//cdn__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      CollectionChestImage = {
        url: 'icon//cch__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      DemiguiseStatueImage = {
        url: 'icon//dst__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      EyeChestImage = {
        url: 'icon//ech__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      FieldGuidePageImage = {
        url: 'icon//rpg__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      FlooNodeImage = {
        url: 'icon//fpt__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      GeneralChestImage = {
        url: 'icon//gch__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      HerbSourceImage = {
        url: 'icon//hsr__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      InflammariBrazierImage = {
        url: 'icon//ibz__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      LegendaryChestImage = {
        url: 'icon//lch__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      LeviosoStatueImage = {
        url: 'icon//lst__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      LoreLetterImage = {
        url: 'icon//lnt__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      LargeBagImage = {
        url: 'icon//lbg__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      MainQuestImage = {
        url: 'icon//mqs__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      MarkImage = {
        url: 'icon//mkr__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      FrameMothImage = {
        url: 'icon//fmt__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      MothFrameImage = {
        url: 'icon//mfr__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      RelationshipQuestImage = {
        url: 'icon//rqs__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      ShopPointImage = {
        url: 'icon//spt__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      SideQuestImage = {
        url: 'icon//sqs__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
      SmallPouchImage = {
        url: 'icon//spc__.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(21, 21), };
    }

    // Pin shape objects
    const Tri40_35Shape = { coords: [0,0,40,0,20,35,19,35], type: 'poly', };
    const Oct34Shape = { coords: [0,8,0,26,8,34,26,34,34,26,34,8,26,0,8,0], type: 'poly', };
    const AncMagShape = { coords: [6,0,8,0,13,10,14,19,14,25,10,34,7,35,2,34,0,25,0,17], type: 'poly', };
    const AssignShape = { coords: [16,0,25,6,32,16,27,24,16,33,7,26,0,16,6,8], type: 'poly', };
    const AstTabShape = { coords: [17,1,22,2,30,16,27,27,23,31,17,32,10,32,4,28,0,20,1,13,5,8,12,5], type: 'poly', };
    const BalloonShape = { coords: [4,0,14,0,18,4,18,17,15,23,15,39,3,39,3,23,0,17,0,4], type: 'poly', };
    const Diamond39Shape = { coords: [19,0,39,19,19,39,0,19], type: 'poly', };
    const ChestShape = { coords: [4,0,33,0,33,19,24,25,1,20,1,3], type: 'poly', };
    const MerTriShape = { coords: [2,0,6,0,17,8,24,15,31,24,31,27,18,30,10,30,6,28,0,21,0,6], type: 'poly', };
    const DemiguiseShape = { coords: [5,0,18,0,22,16,23,36,16,38,7,38,0,36,1,16], type: 'poly', };
    const FGPageShape = { coords: [7,1,31,2,31,7,27,7,23,26,0,26,0,21,4,21], type: 'poly', };
    const FlooNodeShape = { coords: [8,0,13,0,21,5,21,28,13,33,8,33,0,28,0,5], type: 'poly', };
    const HogsmeadeShape = { coords: [14,0,23,8,26,14,16,33,10,27,8,22,3,21,0,15,3,10,8,2], type: 'poly', };
    const HogwartsShape = { coords: [8,0,16,3,24,0,32,5,27,14,32,23,26,30,16,33,6,30,0,23,6,14,0,5], type: 'poly', };
    const InfamousFoeShape = { coords: [5,0,15,0,20,6,20,16,16,20,15,26,10,27,5,26,4,20,0,16,0,6], type: 'poly', };
    const MainQuestShape = { coords: [6,0,11,0,16,3,21,0,26,0,31,6,27,11,32,20,27,28,16,33,5,28,0,20,5,11,1,6], type: 'poly', };
    const RelQuestShape = { coords: [6,1,21,0,33,9,28,32,12,33,0,24], type: 'poly', };
    const SideQuestShape = { coords: [14,0,29,5,28,17,23,27,14,33,7,27,1,17,0,5], type: 'poly', };
    const VillageShape = { coords: [7,2,27,0,33,16,30,24,2,24,0,15], type: 'poly', };

    function loadMarkerFiles(map, locations) {
      // Get the pin data file (json)
      fetch("./hm_pins01.json")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        //console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length);
        // Iterate the json object, pull data
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var lat = parseFloat(data[i].lat);
          var lng = parseFloat(data[i].lng);
          
          // Build the info bubble
          var html = "<div id=\"content\"><div id=\"siteNotice\">"+data[i].siteNotice+
          "</div><h2 id=\"firstHeading\" class=\"firstHeading\">"+data[i].infoHeading+
          "</h2><div id=\"bodyContent\">"+data[i].infoContent+
          "</div><div id=\"bodyRegion\"><h4>"+data[i].region+"</h4></div></div>";
          var label = data[i].label;
          var group = data[i].group;
          var mtype = data[i].mtype;
        
          // Call to create the marker
          var marker = attachMark(label, lat, lng, group, map, mtype, html);
          // Store marker reference
          oPins.push(marker);
        }
      });
    }

    function attachMark(mtitle, mlat, mlng, mgroup, mmap, mtype, mmessage) {
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: mmessage });
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mlat, mlng);

      var ticon = GeneralChestImage;
      var tshape = Oct34Shape;

      if (mgroup == "acpage") {
        ticon = AccioPageImage;
        tshape = AncMagShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "assign") {
        ticon = AssignmentImage;
        tshape = AssignShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "cdungn") {
        ticon = CairnDungeonImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "colche") {
        ticon = CollectionChestImage;
        tshape = ChestShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "demgst") {
        ticon = DemiguiseStatueImage;
        tshape = DemiguiseShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "eyeche") {
        ticon = EyeChestImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "fgpage") {
        ticon = FieldGuidePageImage;
        tshape = FGPageShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "flonet") {
        ticon = FlooNodeImage;
        tshape = FlooNodeShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "genche") {
        ticon = GeneralChestImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "herbsr") {
        ticon = HerbSourceImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "infbrz") {
        ticon = InflammariBrazierImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "legche") {
        ticon = LegendaryChestImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "lorltr") {
        ticon = LoreLetterImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "bigbag") {
        ticon = LargeBagImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "mainqu") {
        ticon = MainQuestImage;
        tshape = MainQuestShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "marker") {
        ticon = MarkImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "frmoth") {
        ticon = FrameMothImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "mtfram") {
        ticon = MothFrameImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "relaqu") {
        ticon = RelationshipQuestImage;
        tshape = RelQuestShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "shoppt") {
        ticon = ShopPointImage;
        tshape = Oct34Shape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "sidequ") {
        ticon = SideQuestImage;
        tshape = SideQuestShape;
      }
      if (mgroup == "smlbag") {
        ticon = SmallPouchImage;
        tshape = Diamond39Shape;
      }

      // Instance the marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: mmap,
        icon: ticon,
        shape: tshape,
        title: mtitle,
        mycategory: mgroup,
        maptype: mtype,
      });

      // Hook to show the info bubble
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(mmap, marker);
      });

      return marker;
    }
```

After noting the shape failing to function:

1. I brought each map's code up to date with current calling, asynchronous and await (promise) code. This also included checking function names, there was no effect to the shape behavior.
2. I made sure there were no variations between implementation in each map. This has changed many times since as I have tried things. No effect.
3. I varied the use of const/var/let for the shape objects and their members though I thought this shouldn't matter, no effect.
4. I explicitly set all shapes in a map to a single shape, no effect.
5. I checked the shapes several times for various errors I could think of, out-of-bound coords, coord list size, no effect.

I looked for some other ideas in the documentation and trying various Google searches. There seems to be no way of finding out how or why the shape object is not applied unless there's a code method of checking in JS that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Please provide code here on Stack Overflow, not just on external sites.. The links to Map 1 and Map 2 are likely to break or become outdated, leading to the question becoming useless to future visitors.

Comment: I have added the code from Map 2. The maps are almost identical except for certain variable names, Map 1 having a larger set of markers, and the unrelated map regions code. Thank you for your comment.